# OpenCV фильтр изображения, сегментация, кластеризация

Tags: python, opencv

Есть вот такая картинка(см. цветную)
История происхождения картинки, есть 3D камера, она предаёт массив с координатами и расстояниями до каждой точки, чем число больше тем пиксель ближе к камере (на картинке чем больше пиксель тем он краснее)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С помощью фильтров я её преобразовываю в черно берую:

```
@dataclass
class Root:
    lower_ = 510
    upper_ = 530
    se1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9, 9))
    se2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (13, 13))

    def new_data(self):
        for frame in glob.glob('\*npy'):

            frame = np.load(frame)
            frame2 = plt.cm.jet(norm(frame))
            cv2.imshow('test', frame2)

            threshold1 = cv2.threshold(frame, self.lower_, 65535, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1]
            threshold2 = cv2.threshold(frame, self.upper_, 65535, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
            threshold = cv2.bitwise_or(threshold1, threshold2)

            mask = cv2.morphologyEx(threshold, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, self.se1)
            mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, self.se2)


Root().new_data()
```

Далее с помощью opencv(connected Components With Stats) нахожу центры объектов:

```
out_img =np.uint8(cv2.threshold(mask, 0, 65535, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)[1])

output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(out_img, 4, cv2.CV_32S)
(numLabels, labels, stats, centroids) = output

for i in centroids:
    cv2.circle(out_img, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), 7, (0, 0, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow('test3', out_img)
```

Но некоторые объекты(обвел красным) сливаются в один, чем я могу разделить их
Может быть есть аналоги connectedComponentsWithStats, или какие ещё фильтры можно добавить чтобы разделить объекты.
Сейчас как видно из кода использую перевод изображения в бинарный вид, морфологическое открытие и закрытие

На выходе хочу получить такую картинку чтобы opencv(connected Components With Stats) смог разделить объекты.

Comment: Upvote за интересную тему и красивую картинку)

Comment: Пробовали ещё больше ограничить вариацию цветов, чтобы на маске появлялись только самые красные участки?

Comment: Для более чувствительной настройки можете попробовать использовать `inRange` вместо `threshold`

Answer (score 4):

Вот, значения в целом, не плохие, можете поиграться, сделать `UH` меньше, получить точки для него, а потом больше и точки для этого значения тоже и отфильтфомать, если точки слишком близки, или если одни точки выходят за пределы некоторой маски.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

def nothing(x):
    pass

cv.namedWindow("Tracking")
cv.createTrackbar("LH", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("LS", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("LV", "Tracking", 0, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("UH", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("US", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("UV", "Tracking", 255, 255, nothing)

cv.setTrackbarPos("LH", "Tracking", 0)
cv.setTrackbarPos("LS", "Tracking", 255)
cv.setTrackbarPos("LV", "Tracking", 129)
cv.setTrackbarPos("LH", "Tracking", 15)
cv.setTrackbarPos("LS", "Tracking", 255)
cv.setTrackbarPos("LV", "Tracking", 255)

path = ...
frame = np.array(cv.imread(path))
hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

while 1:
    l_h = cv.getTrackbarPos("LH", "Tracking")
    l_s = cv.getTrackbarPos("LS", "Tracking")
    l_v = cv.getTrackbarPos("LV", "Tracking")

    u_h = cv.getTrackbarPos("UH", "Tracking")
    u_s = cv.getTrackbarPos("US", "Tracking")
    u_v = cv.getTrackbarPos("UV", "Tracking")

    l_b = np.array([l_h, l_s, l_v])
    u_b = np.array([u_h, u_s, u_v])

    mask = cv.inRange(hsv, l_b, u_b)
    res = cv.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    cv.imshow("frame", frame)
    cv.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv.imshow("res", res)

    if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дополнение с точками:

```py
...

se1 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (9, 9))
se2 = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (13, 13))

while 1:
    ...
    mask = cv.morphologyEx(mask, cv.MORPH_OPEN, se1)
    mask = cv.morphologyEx(mask, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, se2)

    out_img = np.uint8(cv.threshold(mask, 0, 65535, 0)[1])

    output = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(out_img, 4, cv.CV_32S)
    (numLabels, labels, stats, centroids) = output

    for i in centroids:
        cv.circle(out_img, (int(i[0]), int(i[1])), 7, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    cv.imshow('dots', out_img)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я бы ещё подумал о нормализации интенсивности пикселей на результате применении маски и вторичном применении `inRange`

Напмриер

```
...

cv.createTrackbar("alpha", "Tracking", 511, 511, nothing)
cv.createTrackbar("beta", "Tracking", 0, 511, nothing)

...

original_frame = np.array(cv.imread(path))

...

while 1:
   ...

    frame = cv.convertScaleAbs(original_frame,
                               alpha=cv.getTrackbarPos("alpha", "Tracking") / 100,
                               beta=cv.getTrackbarPos("beta", "Tracking") / 10)
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

И если поиграться, можно получить такое, например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
или такое
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Выглядит получше чем у меня) Но некоторые объекты пропали, у меня цель посчитать количество этих кружков, сейчас запущу ваш код, отпишусь

Comment: @Leonid `cv.imwrite('путь/к/файлу.png', image)`

Comment: @Leonid ну, используйте то расширение, что нужно

Comment: @Leonid, извините, но про что вы вообще говорите? Вы же и так уже успешно карту глубин преобразовали в цветное изображение, разве нет?

Comment: И .. В чём проблема?

Comment: Да вот сам не пойму, какой формат у меня для cv2.cvtColor должен быть, я свой массив не преобразовывал в цветное изображение, для вывода imshow сам всё делал, ладно поищу как в hvs свой массив преобразовать)